# Automapper convert to Expandoobject - A lambda Expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Tags: c#, automapper, expandoobject

I am looking to convert the following dictionary to an expandoobject:

```
var dicToConvert = new dictionary<int, CustomAttribute>()
```

My CustomAttribute class has the following properties:

```
int AttributeId
string AttributeValue
int tId
```

I'd like the expandoobject to contain only AttributeId and AttributeValue. I.e.The Value portion of the ExpandoObject shouldn't contain a *whole* 'CustomAttibute', just the 'AttributeValue' from it.

From my initial dictionary, the following works to convert a single KeyValuePair to a KeyValuePair:

```
 CreateMap<KeyValuePair<int, CustomAttribute>, KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            .ConvertUsing(source => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(source.Key.ToString(), source.Value.AttributeValue));
```

The following also works to convert a Dictionary to a Dictionary

```
 CreateMap<Dictionary<int, CustomAttibute>, Dictionary<string, object>>()
            .ConvertUsing(source => source.ToDictionary(e => e.Key.ToString(), e => (object) e.Value.AttributeValue));
```

I can't make the last step in coercing into an expandoobject. I was hoping this might work:

```
 CreateMap<Dictionary<int, CustomAttribute>, ExpandoObject>()
            .ConvertUsing(source =>
            {
                var returnValue = new ExpandoObject();
                foreach (var item in source)
                {
                    returnValue.Add(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.AttributeValue);
                }

                return returnValue;
            });
```

But I get an error saying "A lambda Expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree".

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Show the whole code including the context (i.e. what you're calling `CreateMap` on). It looks like you're getting an overload where `ConvertUsing` takes an `Expression<Func<...>>` rather than a `Func<...>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually just removed that code in the ConvertUsing to a local function which deals with the foreach loop around the incoming dictionary. This just gets rid of the error. I'm sure there'd be a better way to do it in one line but this will do!